# TypeError neo4jrestclient append() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'

Tags: python, typeerror, neo4jrestclient

I am using neo4jrestclient for Neo4j in python and locally it works perfectly. When I host it using webfaction it returns the following error:

```
TypeError at /add/
append() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'
Django Version: 1.6.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
append() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'
Exception Location: /home/kokos/lib/python2.7/neo4jrestclient/client.py in create, line 1036
```

I have no clue where the problem might be. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add some code so I can reproduce the error and take a look?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. See the minimal example below. It seems that `query` call messes up some internal state of library. I'll investigate further.

```
>>> gdb.node()
<Neo4j Node: http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/140>
>>> gdb.query("match (n) where 0 > 1 return n")
<neo4jrestclient.query.QuerySequence object at 0x00000000037A5C88>
>>> gdb.node()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python34\lib\site-packages\neo4jrestclient\client.py", line 1000, in __call__
    return self.create(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python34\lib\site-packages\neo4jrestclient\client.py", line 1036, in create
    returns=NODE)
TypeError: append() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'
```

It's because `query` stores corresponding transaction in global variable and this transaction is tried to be used during later call. However `Transaction` and `QueryTransaction` are different incompatible classes. See https://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client/issues/103.

Comment: It should be fixed in the next 2.0.4.